# Generating Tokens for Apple API Requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, app-store-connect, app-store-connect-api

I create this class to access Apple API Requests

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class AppleAPIService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


            Path privateKeyPath = Paths.get("/Users/ricardolle/IdeaProjects/mystic-planets-api/src/main/resources/cert/AuthKey_5425KFDYSC.p8");

    String keyContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(privateKeyPath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("Original Key Content: " + keyContent); // Logging the original content
    keyContent = keyContent.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // Remove all whitespaces and newlines, more robust than just replacing \n
    System.out.println("Processed Key Content: " + keyContent); // Logging processed content
    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyContent);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    PrivateKey pk =  kf.generatePrivate(spec);

    Map<String, Object> headerMap = new HashMap<>();

    headerMap.put("alg", "ES256"); // Algorithm, e.g., RS256 for asymmetric signing
    headerMap.put("kid", "5425KFDYSC"); // Algorithm, e.g., RS256 for asymmetric signing
    headerMap.put("typ", "JWT"); //
    
    String issuer = "68a6Se82-111e-47e3-e053-5b8c7c11a4d1"; // Replace with your issuer
    //String subject = "subject"; // Replace with your subject
    long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date issuedAt = new Date(nowMillis);
    Date expiration = new Date(nowMillis + 3600000); // Expiration time (1 hour in this example)


    JwtBuilder jwtBuilder = Jwts.builder()
            .setHeader(headerMap)
            .setIssuer(issuer)
            .setAudience("appstoreconnect-v1")
            .setIssuedAt(issuedAt)
            .signWith(pk)
            .setExpiration(expiration);
    
    // Print the JWT header as a JSON string
    String headerJson = jwtBuilder.compact();

    System.out.println("JWT Header: " + headerJson);

    String apiUrl = "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps";

    // Create headers with Authorization
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + headerJson);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    // Create HttpEntity with headers
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    // Make GET request using RestTemplate
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            apiUrl,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            entity,
            String.class
    );

    // Handle the response
    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        String responseBody = response.getBody();
        System.out.println("Response: " + responseBody);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: " + response.getStatusCodeValue());
    }

    // Print the JWT payload as a JSON string
    String payloadJson = jwtBuilder.compact();
    System.out.println("JWT Payload: " + payloadJson);
```

but I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: "{<EOL>?"errors": [{<EOL>??"status": "401",<EOL>??"code": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",<EOL>??"title": "Authentication credentials are missing or invalid.",<EOL>??"detail": "Provide a properly configured and signed bearer token, and make sure that it has not expired. Learn more about Generating Tokens for API Requests https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=api-generating-tokens"<EOL>?}]<EOL>}"
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:932)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:881)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:781)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:663)
at com.mysticriver.service.AppleAPIService.main(AppleAPIService.java:77)
```

Opening the file with an editor gives me this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQg5Fu6zyvQDhgGvevK
pe4OYs32cFSz1oxLd/YCYWJSOPagCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAATrJf+q7/nieM4y
V9/v71e/Xl/aS+LF4riW5lkcld8lFQB5ekivp5T7w57t6nqp8rCqtq79nEhIyzDr
hCMnmLEk
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: I hope the "kid" is not real one.

Comment: no, just changed some letters. Thanks

Comment: thanks, I have the same error with EC

Comment: thanks, I have the same error... :-( even with another new key

Comment: Can you provide your .p8 file? When I'm trying to sign up in the developer program, it's asking for money for subscription

Comment: Thanks, now seems I can read the file properly, just went back to the original error

Comment: This question sustained significant changes after answers were given, and based on one of the answers below, answer material was invalidated as a result. Consequently this question is liable to be closed after the bounty expires. (You can if you wish roll back to the earlier version of the question, and then re-play the edits as updates instead).

Answer (score 4):

Original question (before edit): `401 Unauthorized`: that should mean the [authentication token (JWT)](https://jwt.io/introduction/) you are using is either not properly formatted, not signed correctly, or expired.

From your code, you might be missing the "signing the JWT with your private key" step. The JWT must be signed with your private key for the Apple API to authenticate it.
See "[Creating API Keys for App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api)" to create the key.
Then, to sign the JWT with said private key:

```java
PrivateKey privateKey = // Load your private key here
JwtBuilder jwtBuilder = Jwts.builder()
        .setHeader(headerMap)
        .setIssuer(issuer)
        .setAudience("appstoreconnect-v1")
        .setIssuedAt(issuedAt)
        .setExpiration(expiration)
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, privateKey); // Signing the JWT
```

See "[REST Security With JWT Using Java and Spring Security](https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java)" from [Dejan Milosevic](https://www.toptal.com/resume/dejan-milosevic).

Also, check that the JWT structure (header, payload, signature) is correct as per Apple's guidelines.
And, as usual, add some error handling to provide more informative feedback in case of failures.

```java
try {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            apiUrl,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            entity,
            String.class
    );
    // Rest of the code
} catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
    System.out.println("HTTP Error: " + ex.getStatusCode());
    System.out.println("Error Body: " + ex.getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```

---

Your updated code now includes:

- Loading the private key from a `.p8` file, which is typically used for Apple API authentication. It uses `KeyFactory` with "RSA" for generating the `PrivateKey`.
- Signing the JWT with the loaded private key, a necessary step for authentication with the Apple API.

You now have a `InvalidKeySpecException` indicating an issue with the key specification or format.

The `.p8` file likely contains an [EC (Elliptic Curve) private key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECPrivateKeySpec.html), not RSA. So the `KeyFactory` instance should use `"EC"` instead of `"RSA"`.
Make sure the `.p8` file is not corrupted and correctly formatted.

```java
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC"); // Change from "RSA" to "EC"
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
```

And, again, add error handling for loading the private key to pinpoint issues.

```java
try {
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
    // Rest of the code
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // More informative error output
    return;
}
```

---

For the third edit:

`jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(ECKeyFactory.java:168)`should indicate a problem with loading the private key from the `.p8` file. The stack trace suggests that the issue lies in the `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`, which is unable to decode the key.

You have updated the `KeyFactory` instance to use "EC" instead of "RSA", which is correct for Apple's `.p8` private keys. But despite this change, the `InvalidKeySpecException` persists, indicating the problem is not with the choice of key factory algorithm (RSA or EC), but rather with the format or content of the key file.

The error message "`Unable to decode key`" and "`extra data at the end`" suggest that the `.p8` file might not be in the correct [PKCS#8 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_8).

So try and make sure the `.p8` file is a proper PKCS#8 format private key. It should start with "`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`" and end with "`-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`". Any additional data or formatting issues can cause the error.

If the `.p8` file contains any headers or footers (like "`BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`"), these need to be removed before being passed to `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`.

The key data in the `.p8` file is typically Base64 encoded. Make sure it is correctly decoded to its binary form before using it in `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`.

```java
String keyContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(privateKeyPath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                        .replaceAll("\\n", "")
                        .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                        .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyContent);
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey);
```

With some error handling:

```java
try {
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
    // Rest of the code
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // More detailed error information
    return;
}
```

---

If you still have an issue with loading the private key, even after formatting and Base64 decoding the content, that would suggest an issue with the key itself or the way it is being processed.

I will assume your  `.p8` file does starts with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and ends with `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`, and that it is complete and not truncated. You have generated a new key from the Apple Developer account, so you can compare with your previous one.

Make sure the Base64 decoding is happening correctly. Incorrect decoding can lead to an invalid key specification.
And make sure the file reading process is not altering the key content in any way. For example, make sure the character encoding used to read the file matches the encoding of the file.

```java
public static PrivateKey loadPrivateKey(Path privateKeyPath) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    String keyContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(privateKeyPath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("Original Key Content: " + keyContent); // Logging the original content
    keyContent = keyContent.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                           .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                           .replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // Remove all whitespaces and newlines, more robust than just replacing \n
    System.out.println("Processed Key Content: " + keyContent); // Logging processed content
    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyContent);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
}
```

This is basically your code, but in a function set to throw exception in case of error, with a replaceAll using  `\s+` instead of `\s+`, and with some logging (the `System.out.println`)

Or, for testing, try a more direct approach to decoding:

```java
String keyContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(privateKeyPath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
keyContent = keyContent.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                        .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                        .replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // Remove all whitespaces and newlines
byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyContent);
```

In any case, try using a tool like OpenSSL to check the validity of the key. That can help determine if the issue lies with the key itself or the Java code.

```bash
openssl pkcs8 -in [path-to-your-key].p8 -nocrypt -topk8
```

That command should output the key details if the file is correctly formatted. If it fails, the problem likely is with the key file itself.

Comment: This is extremely helpful information, but is may be too much for too little gain. The question is likely to be closed since the old version of the question has been overwritten by a new version, and IMO that's too much mess for curators to fix. If you can roll back any major question edits when you see them, that may be a better policy - the OP can be encouraged to add those changes as updates at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution is to use **BountyCastle** Library.

This library will takes care of everything when it comes to removal of the unnecessary headers and decoding the Base64 PEM data.

**Note:** BountyCastle has a good support for **Elliptic Curve Cryptography** Algorithm parsing.

Also, you try to use `com.auth0:java-jwt` dependency instead as it provides much more functionalities than `io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt` dependency.

Add this dependency in the pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk18on</artifactId>
    <version>1.76</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Change/Update your logic to this:

```
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class AppleAPIService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(
                new FileReader("/Users/ricardolle/IdeaProjects/mystic-planets-api/src/main/resources/cert/AuthKey_5425KFDYSC.p8"))) {

            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
            PemObject pemObj = pemReader.readPemObject();
            byte[] content = pemObj.getContent();
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(content);
            ECPrivateKey privateKey = (ECPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

            String token = JWT.create()
                    .withKeyId("5525KFDYSC")
                    .withIssuer("69a6de82-121e-48e3-e053-5b8c7c11a4d1")
                    .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1)))
                    .withClaim("scope", Collections.singletonList("GET /v1/apps"))
                    .withAudience("appstoreconnect-v1")
                    .sign(Algorithm.ECDSA256(privateKey));

            System.out.println("JWT token: " + token);


            // Create headers with Authorization
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setBearerAuth(token);
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            // Create HttpEntity with headers
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

            // Make GET request using RestTemplate
            ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(
                    "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps",
                    HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

            // Handle the response
            if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
                String responseBody = response.getBody();
                System.out.println("Response: " + responseBody);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: " + response.getStatusCodeValue());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Please look at this Apple Developer thread forum question to resolve your issue - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707220

If the above thread is still not resolving your issue, then try adding **bid (apple bundle id)** via `withClaims("bid", "put your bundle id")`

That's all.

Comment: That is also a good option. Upvoted.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" io.jsonwebtoken.security.InvalidKeyException: RSA signing keys must be RSAKey instances.
 at io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm.assertValid(SignatureAlgorithm.java:424)
 at io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm.assertValidSigningKey(SignatureAlgorithm.java:315)
 at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:112)
 at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:138)

Comment: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid RSA private key

Comment: I aslo edited my  question adding the content of the ceritifcate.. Now having: ..."main" io.jsonwebtoken.security.InvalidKeyException: HMAC signing keys must be SecretKey instances.
 at io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm.assertValid(SignatureAlgorithm.java:352)
 at io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm.assertValidSigningKey(SignatureAlgorithm.java:315)
 at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:112)
 at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:138)
 at com.mysticriver.service.AppleAPIService.main(AppleAPIService.java:62)

Comment: @NuñitoCalzada I have just updated my answer based on what you have updated. Check now.

Comment: thanks. Went back to the original error: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: "{<EOL>?"errors": [{<EOL>??"status": "401",<EOL>??"code": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",<EOL>??"title": "Authentication credentials are missing or invalid.",<EOL>??"detail": "Provide a properly configured and signed bearer token, and make sure that it has not expired. Learn more about Generating Tokens for API Requests https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=api-generating-tokens"<EOL>?}]<EOL>}"
 at ...

Comment: @Anish https://file.io/Sp7TJldtaeML

Comment: @NuñitoCalzada Thanks will try now.

Comment: @NuñitoCalzada I updated again please check now.

Comment: @AnishB. same error :-(

Comment: @NuñitoCalzada Can you please check the link that I have provided in my answer and  try adding bid in the request.

Comment: @NuñitoCalzada At least, if you can kindle provide bundle id.

Comment: I don't have bundle id

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Try providing an expiration no greater than `20` minutes, let's say, `15`, for instance (although the documentation states no greater than I am afraid it should be less than `20`):

```java
Date expiration = new Date(nowMillis + 15 * 60 * 1000);
```

## Details

The last version of the code provided in your answer is mostly fine.

I think the problem has to do with the lifetime of the token you are specifying, one hour.

As explained in the [Apple Developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests#3028613) when describing the `exp`iration JWT payload field:

> The token’s expiration time in Unix epoch time. Tokens that expire more than
> 20 minutes into the future are not valid except for resources listed in
> [Determine the Appropriate Token Lifetime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests#3878467).

The referenced [Determine the Appropriate Token Lifetime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests#3878467) documentation states that the App Store Connect accepts a token with a lifetime greater than 20 minutes if:

> - The token defines a scope.
> - The scope only includes `GET` requests.
> - The resources in the scope allow long-lived tokens.

Your Java code meets the first two conditions but not the third one: the aforementioned documentation lists the resources that can accept long-lived tokens and the [List Apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_apps) endpoint you are using, in general, the [Apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/app_store/apps) resource, is not included in it.

As indicated, to solve the problem, please, try defining an expiration less than `20` minutes when performing your request. For example:

```java
Date expiration = new Date(nowMillis + 15 * 60 * 1000);
```

The rest of your code looks fine: please, only, be aware that all the information you provided when generating your JWT token is the right one, and that the key is not revoked and it has been assigned a role authorized to perform the request.

Please, consider for reference [this related article](https://dev.to/hasone/generate-jwt-token-for-apple-store-connect-api-using-python-3j5h), I think it exemplifies very well how to perform the operation.

Comment: Good catch on the `exp`iration JWT payload field. Upvoted.

Comment: same error with an expiration not greater than 20 minutes :-(

Comment: I am sorry to hear that it didn't work properly. Have you tried a small duration, `500` or `1200` seconds, for instance? In addition, from time to time - see for example [this](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/19072) and [this other](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20270) issues - the problem suddenly appears in the App Store Connect API and only retrying the request helps to mitigate the issue: it could be another thing to try as well, perform a second exchange if the error is raised. I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, of course, you already tested `1200` seconds. Sorry.

Comment: @NuñitoCalzada Were you able to test with an `exp` value less than `20` minutes? Although the documentation states no longer than `20` minutes, I think that `20` minutes itself may not be included in the boundary, the expiration should be less than `20` minutes. If you provided the right information when configuring your token I think the only possible reason of the error is either the mentioned expiration limit or that you assigned a role to the key not authorized to perform the request. I included a companion article that greatly exemplifies the configuration process: I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, with the same results -:(

Comment: I am sorry to hear that... Thank you for the feedback. I am running out of ideas... Please, as a last resource: 1. Check that you assigned the key a [role](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/) with the appropriate permissions. 2. Check that the key is not [revoked](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/revoking_api_keys). 3. Check that the clock of the machine from which you are performing the request is not early or late. Finally, please, consider review the configuration steps outlined in the article I mentioned in my answer, I think it could be of help.